# Does Workflow in repeat stage effect the system speed

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, designer-workflow

I have created an item with due date, and assigned to Workflow in the repeat stage while Due date is equal to today’s date.
Is this will effect on the system speed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a `While` action, the workflow will be loaded into the SharePoint Timer service (owstimer.exe) every 5 minutes so it checks the conditions.
As this happens in the Timer service, this should not really impact the Web requests performances. 
However, it also highly depends on the number of workflow instances running at the same time. If you have 1000s of instances, an impact could be seen, while with a few instances I really doubt you'll notice any change.